# Having Problems calculating the volume with 3 input values.

Tags: swift, xcode

i'm a fairly new programmer and i've just started on Xcode. Atm i am trying to make a calculator that can calculate the total volume from 3 input values (Height, length & width) but i can't seem to make it calculate it. right now i am able to enter a value and click the button and then it crashes. 
Thanks in advance!
here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var HeightInput: NSTextField!


@IBOutlet weak var LengthInput: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var WidthInput: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Result: NSTextField!


@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: Any) {
    var height = Int(HeightInput.stringValue)

    var width = Int(WidthInput.stringValue)

    var length = Int(LengthInput.stringValue)

    if height == 0
    {
       Result.stringValue = "Error"
    }
    else{
        var result = width! * height! * length!
            Result.stringValue = "the volume is: \(result)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? Have you verified that the `NSTextField`s are not `nil`? Have you verified that `height/width/length` are not `nil`? – Learn to **debug!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: Any) {

    let height = Int(HeightInput.stringValue) ?? 0
    let width = Int(WidthInput.stringValue) ?? 0
    let length = Int(LengthInput.stringValue) ?? 0

    let result = height * width * length

    if result == 0 {
        Result.stringValue = "Error"
    else {
        Result.stringValue = "The volume is: \(result)"
    }
}
```

When converting your label value to an integer, it will return an optional (meaning it could be nil). When you are calculating your result, you are force-unwrapping these optionals with the `!`.

I recommend conditionally unwrapping these values. Using `??` meaning that if the value is nil, it will default to whatever you put after the `??`.

Comment: You are still force-unwrapping the variables.

Comment: Good point @MartinR. I didn't properly test my solution first. I've changed it now.

Comment: the same problem still occurs when i press the button to calculate the values. i can see in my console that it multiplies the values correctly, but it seems to be having problems outputting the value to the label. Any ideas?
Thanks so far. i've already learned a lot

Comment: Make sure all the `@IBOutlets` are connected. If you wanna learn to code well, I recommend using SwiftLint to your project to keep you away from filling your code with forced unwraps :)